# jQuery animation issue with swapping div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a script that switches the position of div's with a jQuery animation.

The problem that I'm running into is that if I want to swap 2 div's from different line's, this works fine, but if there is another `div` on the second line it will be affected by the animation.

I want the second `div` on the second line to stay in place while the animation is happening.

If you expand the snippet and hover on the last div of the first line and click the arrow to the right you will see what I mean.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".button-row .btn", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var select = $(this).closest("[class^=col-]");
  var value = $(this).attr('value');
  var section = $(this).closest(".row");
  if (select.offset().top == section.offset().top) {}
  if (value == 'weg') {
    select.remove();
  } else if (value == 'moveL') {
    var selectprev = select.prev();
    var selectnext = select.next();
    if (select.offset().top == selectprev.offset().top) {
      var left = select.width() + 30;

      select.animate({
        marginLeft: left * -2,
      }, {
        duration: 750,
        queue: false
      });
      selectprev.animate({
        marginLeft: left,
      }, {
        duration: 750,
        queue: false
      });
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("[class^=col-]").css('margin-left', '0px');
        select.clone().insertBefore(selectprev);
        selectprev.clone().insertBefore(selectprev);
        selectprev.remove();
        select.remove();
        updatebuttons();
      }, 750);
    } else {
      var left = select.width() + 30;
      var top = select.height();
      select.animate({
        marginLeft: left * 2,
        marginTop: top * -2,
      }, {
        duration: 750,
        queue: false
      });
      selectprev.animate({
        marginLeft: left * -2,
        marginTop: top * 1,
      }, {
        duration: 750,
        queue: false
      });
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("[class^=col-]").css('margin', '0px');
        select.clone().insertBefore(selectprev);
        selectprev.clone().insertBefore(selectprev);
        selectprev.remove();
        select.remove();
        updatebuttons();
      }, 750);
    }
  } else if (value == 'moveR') {
    var selectprev = select.prev();
    var selectnext = select.next();
    if (select.offset().top == selectnext.offset().top) {
      var left = select.width() + 30;
      selectnext.animate({
        marginLeft: left * -2,
      }, {
        duration: 750,
        queue: false
      });
      select.animate({
        marginLeft: left,
      }, {
        duration: 750,
        queue: false
      });
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("[class^=col-]").css('margin-left', '0px');
        select.clone().insertAfter(select.next());
        select.next().clone().insertBefore(select);
        selectnext.remove();
        select.remove();
        updatebuttons();
      }, 750);
    } else {
      var left = select.width() + 30;
      var top = select.height();
      selectnext.animate({
        marginLeft: left * 2,
        marginTop: top * -2,
      }, {
        duration: 750,
        queue: false
      });
      select.animate({
        marginLeft: left * -2,
        marginTop: top * 1,
      }, {
        duration: 750,
        queue: false
      });
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("[class^=col-]").css('margin', '0px');
        select.clone().insertAfter(select.next());
        select.next().clone().insertBefore(select);
        selectnext.remove();
        select.remove();
        updatebuttons();
      }, 750);
    }
  } else if (value == 'clone') {
    select.clone().insertAfter(select);
  }
  updatebuttons();

});

function updatebuttons() {
  $('.button-links').show();
  $('.button-rechts').show();
  $('.button-prullenbak').show();
  buttonsdisabel();
}

function buttonsdisabel() {
  $("section").each(function() {

    $(this).find("div[class^=col-]").first().find('.button-links').hide();
    $(this).find("div[class^=col-]").last().find('.button-rechts').hide();
    if ($(this).find('[class^=col-]').length == 1) {
      $(this).find("div[class^=col-]").find('.button-prullenbak').hide();
    }
    $('.button-row').fadeIn();
  });
}
$(document).on("mouseover", "section", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).find('[class^=col-]').length >= 1 && $(this).find('.snippet-col-nav').length == 0) {
    $(this).find('[class^=col-]').each(function() {
      $(this).append('<div class="button-row snippet-col-nav btn-group" style="position:absolute;height: 56px; top:0;right:20px;">' +
        '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary button-links" value="moveL" title="Schuif 1 plek naar links"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>' +
        '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary button-rechts" value="moveR" title="Schuif 1 plek naar rechts"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>' +
        '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-inverse" value="clone" title="Clone"><i class="fa fa-clone"></i></a>' +
        '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger button-prullenbak" value="weg" title="Vewijder"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>' +
        '</div>');
      $('.button-row').hide();
    });
  }
  updatebuttons();
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", "section", function(e) {
  $('.button-row').remove();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="afbbox-3x-v4-1" class="afbbox-3x-v4 pv-30">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="editContent">
      <h2>Kopregel</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-4 cloneable">
        <div class="image-box style-2 mb-20 bordered dark-bg">
          <div class="iviewer_wrapper">
            <div class="iviewer">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/360x270" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="body">
            <div class="body-inner">
              <p class="small mb-10 text-muted"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> <span class="editContent">div 1 </span> <i class="pl-10 icon-tag-1"></i> Categorie</p>
              <div class="editContent">
                <p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam atque ipsam nihil, adipisci rem minus? Voluptatem distinctio laborum porro aspernatur.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-gray-transparent btn-animated btn-sm margin-clear">Lees verder<i class="fa fa-arrow-right pl-10"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 cloneable">
        <div class="image-box style-2 mb-20 bordered dark-bg">
          <div class="iviewer_wrapper">
            <div class="iviewer">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/360x270" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="body">
            <div class="body-inner">
              <p class="small mb-10 text-muted"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> <span class="editContent">Jun, 2016</span> <i class="pl-10 icon-tag-1"></i> Categorie</p>
              <div class="editContent">
                <p>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam atque ipsam nihil, adipisci rem minus? Voluptatem distinctio laborum porro aspernatur.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-gray-transparent btn-animated btn-sm margin-clear">Lees verder<i class="fa fa-arrow-right pl-10"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 cloneable">
        <div class="image-box style-2 mb-20 bordered dark-bg">
          <div class="iviewer_wrapper">
            <div class="iviewer">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/360x270" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="body">
            <div class="body-inner">
              <p class="small mb-10 text-muted"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> <span class="editContent">div 1 </span> <i class="pl-10 icon-tag-1"></i> Categorie</p>
              <div class="editContent">
                <p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam atque ipsam nihil, adipisci rem minus? Voluptatem distinctio laborum porro aspernatur.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-gray-transparent btn-animated btn-sm margin-clear">Lees verder<i class="fa fa-arrow-right pl-10"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 cloneable">
        <div class="image-box style-2 mb-20 bordered dark-bg">
          <div class="iviewer_wrapper">
            <div class="iviewer">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/360x270" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="body">
            <div class="body-inner">
              <p class="small mb-10 text-muted"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> <span class="editContent">Jun, 2016</span> <i class="pl-10 icon-tag-1"></i> Categorie</p>
              <div class="editContent">
                <p>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam atque ipsam nihil, adipisci rem minus? Voluptatem distinctio laborum porro aspernatur.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-gray-transparent btn-animated btn-sm margin-clear">Lees verder<i class="fa fa-arrow-right pl-10"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 cloneable">
        <div class="image-box style-2 mb-20 bordered dark-bg">
          <div class="iviewer_wrapper">
            <div class="iviewer">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/360x270" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="body">
            <div class="body-inner">
              <p class="small mb-10 text-muted"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> <span class="editContent">Jun, 2016</span> <i class="pl-10 icon-tag-1"></i> Categorie</p>
              <div class="editContent">
                <p>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam atque ipsam nihil, adipisci rem minus? Voluptatem distinctio laborum porro aspernatur.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-gray-transparent btn-animated btn-sm margin-clear">Lees verder<i class="fa fa-arrow-right pl-10"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Edit:** I was going trough my questions and saw this was never given an answer.
I have found a solution back in time. By placing divs on the places that swap. And making the divs that swap position absolute it will solve my issue.

Comment: That is nice UX. I like your animation. Have you tried putting the elements inside wrappers that handlle the flowed responsive layout and then when you reorder them, just move the contents? In other words don't reposition the bootstrap columns, just make an additional full width element inside the col- elements to house the actual elements?

Comment: @JasonB i have tried it without sucseeding. But came to the conclution that for the reason where im going to use this i need to meve the col- and not the text inside it.

Comment: Bummer. Another thought is to find the current position on screen of all sibling columns and absolutely position all of them while animating and reordering the dom, then remove those style overrides.